# How to check string start with character validation

Tags: php, validation

I need to put validation that Name should not start with space, . or _

After entering name then after u can add.

```
Valid :
My Name
My.Name
My_Name

In Valid:
 My Name
_My Name
.My Name
```

I made a function

```
  function validName($name) {

    $name_first_character = substr($name, 0, 1);

    if ($name_first_character == '.' || $name_first_character == '-') {
      return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
  }
```

But still it's not checking for space. Do I need to do with `preg_match`?

Comment: how about ctype_alpha() ?

Comment: _But still it's not checking for space._ How about you add a `==` space to the `if`?

Comment: `|| $name_first_character == ' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex would probably be easier. You are missing some of the characters you don't want to allow. It also would be easier to write it with an `in_array`.

```
if (in_array($name_first_character, array('.', '-', ' ', '_'))) {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/SGM4T

A regex could be:

```
if (preg_match('/^[-._ ]/', $name)) {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/cu6vi

The space in the character class can be replaced with a `\s` if you want to disallow any type of white space.

`^` is the start of the string
`[]` creates a character class and allows any 1 of the characters inside it. If a `-` is used and isn't at the start or end it will create a range. For example `1-9` would be numbers between 1 and 9.

Answer (score 1):

instead of checking for what you dont want, how about checking for what you do want

```
 function validName($name) {

  $name_first_character = substr($name, 0, 1);

   if (ctype_alpha($name_first_character)) { 
       return TRUE;
    }else{
       return FALSE;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for space, you could trim the string and compare if you still have the same variable. Something like would check for leading/trailing whitespace

```
$temp  = $text
$trimmed = trim($temp);
return $temp == $text
```